# UDP project wont connect to other computers, either on the network or online

Tags: vb.net

i'm currently working on a project for my computer science class in VB.Net and i cant figure out how to use UDP clients across computers. i can get it working so if i open the reciever and broadcaster on the same computer it works, but if i move the reciever to another computer it doesnt recieve the message. Im not sure where exactly im going wrong as im very new to UDP clients in general, any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my broadcaster program

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1
    Private Const port As Integer = 9653                         'Port number to send/recieve data on
    Private Const broadcastAddress As String = "255.255.255.255"
    Private udp As New UdpClient(broadcastAddress, port)



    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        udp.EnableBroadcast = True
        Dim bytes() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text)
        Try
            udp.Send(bytes, bytes.Length)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

and here is my reciever program

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Private UDP_Thread As New Thread(AddressOf UDP_Receive_Thread)
    Private Running As Boolean = True

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        UDP_Thread.IsBackground = True
        UDP_Thread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UDP_Receive_Thread()
        Dim receivingUDpClient As New UdpClient(9653)
        Dim RemoteIPEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9653)

        While Running
            Try
                Dim receiveBytes As Byte() = receivingUDpClient.Receive(RemoteIPEndPoint)
                Dim returnData As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes)
                Me.Invoke(Sub() Label1.Text = returnData)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End While

    End Sub
End Class
```

Any suggestions of how to fix it, better alternatives to use and just any helpful tips would be much appreciated